# Reopen audit failed, unsure why

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

Today, I came upon [this review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/12408176) in the Reopen Votes queue. I voted to keep the question closed for a couple of reasons:

- The question is written in poor English (which can be edited, but that's not the point of this queue)
- Because of this, the question is quite unclear
- The question is very broad

Especially the last (for which the question was supposedly closed in the audit) seems valid to me as the question is pretty much (from what I can make up from it):

> I am currently solving problem X with method Y. What other methods are there to achieve this?

This is a very broad question that can result in numerous very different answers. The current answers to the question actually prove as much. Therefor it won't result in a very specific Q&A and I opted to keep the question closed as too broad. Was I really that wrong by thinking that?

What would be valid reasons to reopen this question? There were no edits made to the question, it was just a simple re-open vote that needed to be confirmed or denied.

Comment: It's a bad audit.  Happens often.  In fact, this is the third complaint about lousy audits today.  Wish SE would do something about it.

Comment: "I voted to keep the question closed" I don't see close votes. why?

Comment: Believe it or not, the answerer managed to cover the entire "broad topic" in a very short answer. Looks like on Android specifically, there are not so many solutions.

Comment: @Braiam I meant "voted" in the review queue, not on the actual question. Given it's already answered and accepted, I'm not sure if it's still a good idea to do so anyway. But that's probably already asked and answered somewhere else on meta.

Comment: If you believe it to be a bad audit, then you shouldn't just complain in meta. Audits are basically selected due user behavior at large, so if nobody tries to close it, other people might be failing it too. If you believe is a bad question, is a bad question. [Answers doesn't matter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227044/213575).